# how to use service name inside kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, charts, server, service, ip

i want to replace this two value (**.***.*.*** = @IP)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bK0cu.png)

with service name
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/863OY.png)

Any solution plz ?

Answer (score 0):

this is my service his name is api

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api
  labels:
    app: api
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      nodePort: 30001
      targetPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      name: api
  selector:
    app: api
```

and this is my deployement

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: api
  name: api
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: api
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: api
          image: einstore/einstore-core:0.1.1
          env:
            - name: APICORE_STORAGE_LOCAL_ROOT
              value: "/home/einstore"
            - name: APICORE_SERVER_NAME
              value: "Einstore - Enterprise AppStore"
            - name: APICORE_SERVER_MAX_UPLOAD_FILESIZE
              value: "50"
            - name: APICORE_DATABASE_HOST
              value: "postgres"
            - name: APICORE_DATABASE_USER
              value: "einstore"
            - name: APICORE_DATABASE_PASSWORD
              value: "einstore"
            - name: APICORE_DATABASE_DATABASE
              value: "einstore"
            - name: APICORE_DATABASE_PORT
              value: "5432"
            - name: APICORE_DATABASE_LOGGING
              value: "false"
            - name: APICORE_JWT_SECRET
              value: "secret"
            - name: APICORE_STORAGE_S3_ENABLED
              value: "false"
            - name: APICORE_STORAGE_S3_BUCKET
              value: "~"
            - name: APICORE_STORAGE_S3_ACCESS_KEY
              value: "~"
            - name: APICORE_STORAGE_S3_REGION
              value: "~"
            - name: APICORE_STORAGE_S3_SECRET_KEY
              value: "~"
            - name: APICORE_SERVER_URL
              value: "http://**.***.*.***:30001/"
```

when i try to replace the *** with my machine @ip Everything works,But what I need is to change that so that there is the name of the service so that I can deploy the app in any other machine
the first solution LGTM but i get this error

```
curl http://api.einstore:8080/
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: api.einstore
```

NB: einstore= the name of my namespace